# On Python is the `i` variable defined inherently?

Tags: python, beginner

I am new to this whole landscape, please need some hand holding at first, I can't find a beginner section. Can someone please tell me if `i` is defined inherently in Python. Can i test for this: what type of object is `i`?

```
squares=['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'blue']

for i, square in enumerate(squares):
    print(i, square)
```

Square `i` is not even defined? There is no programming error.

Comment: Welcome to the forum, please make sure you use okay language and code highlighting etc when posting. Cheers!

Comment: This is not a question about data science. This question is better suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

No, `i` is not predefined. If you use `enumarate()`, `i` (or whatever you may call it) is a count: [see the docs](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html).

```
squares=['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'purple', 'blue']

for i, square in enumerate(squares):
    print(i, square)
```

Gives you:

```
0 red
1 yellow
2 green
3 purple
4 blue
```

You can also set a start value for the count (Python by default starts counting by `0`):

```
for i, square in enumerate(squares,10):
    print(i, square)
```

Gives you:

```
10 red
11 yellow
12 green
13 purple
14 blue
```

In case you just want to loop over a list, you can write:

```
for i in squares:
    print(i)
```

Which gives you:

```
red
yellow
green
purple
blue
```